# Uncompress multiple nested tar.gz files

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, tar

How the folder layout is now:

```
Directory0
  Directory01
    - File1.tar.gz
  Directory02
    - File02.tar.gz
  Directory03
    - File03.tar.gz
```

How I would like it to be:

```
Directory0
  Directory01
      - File1.tar.gz
      - File 01-01
      - File01-02
  Directory02
      - File02.tar.gz
      - File02-01
      - File02-02
  Directory03
      - File03.tar.gz
      - File03-01
      - File03-02
```

I would like to know how to uncompress the files at once, but that the uncompressed files are in the same folder as the tar.gz files. In the command below, the files are uncompressed, but in the same folder.

```
 find /lantri/jornais/jornal-fsp -name "*.tar.gz" -exec tar xvzf '{}' \;
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure of what you want, partly because you have not said how the `tar` file is formatted, and it's unclear what your second example represents (what your command does, or what you want). What I think you need is more control over the directory where the files will be written. In `bash`, instead of `-exec` in `find`, you can use something like `find /lantri/jornais/jornal-fsp -name "*.tar.gz" | while read -r f; do tar -C "${f%/*}" -xvzf ${f##*/}; done`. By piping to a `read` command, you handle each archive in isolation and parse its name to give the directories you need.

Answer (score 0):

`find /lantri/jornais/jornal-fsp -name "*.tar.gz" -exec cd $(dirname '{}') && tar xvf '{}' -C ./ \;`

Otherwise you could run a find command, and move only files to your chosen directory after extracting everything.

`find ./Directory0 -type f -name 'File*' -exec mv -i {} ./  \;`

---

Answers borrowed and adapted from:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/45349/how-to-extract-files-to-another-directory-using-tar-command
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/how-can-i-move-files-by-type-recursively-from-a-directory-and-its-sub-directorie

Comment: Just realised each of your tars is embedded, going to try and fix that now for you.